# Strapi findOne with populate doesnt populate any data

Tags: strapi

I was trying to implement slug and it worked, but populate goes wrong.
Nothing comes up while populating

Following is the code for query

```
const entity = await strapi.db.query('api::news-detail.news-detail').findOne(
    {
        where: { slug }, populate: true
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Settings > Users & Permissions plugin > Roles > [your role]** and verify that the related fields  in the object you request, all have necessary permissions enabled. To show up in an object, the content-type of a relation field must be readable (find/findOne) for your current role.